# Make animated play/pause button like head space app

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, audio, playback

For Downloading and playing **AUDIO**, I want to make a **play-pause Button with Animation** LIKE head space app audio player.

See the animation carefully in Video.:-

http://youtu.be/ZgY-OTJj4Fo

Please give me any Reference Code/Demo App/Tutorial/Code for the kind of animation..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial:

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/

It's very similar, should help you to start with this kind of control.

Comment: @ Piotr , Circular slider is Ok. But we want the water flow type animation on button. (As you can see on play/pause button in the video.)